# How to run a command when any process starts?

Tags: linux, bash, script, sh

I have an sh script to update my wallpaper which uses [pscircle](https://gitlab.com/mildlyparallel/pscircle) in order to display running processes. The script runs every five seconds to update the wallpaper, but I would like it so that the script runs whenever any process starts or stops. Is this possible?

Edit 1: Could also just make it check the number of processes running under my user name

Edit 2: Might have to add an exception for pscircle itself

Comment: While it might be possible, it would also be a big mistake: When the `pscircle` process starts it would create another trigger, which would start `pscircle` ...

Comment: Ah yea I didn't realize that. Might have to create an exception of some sort

Comment: And of course you start `pscircle` with a `bash` script, so there is another exception, and the wallpaper change starts a dbus session, creating another process, plus what cron and friends do ... you'd end up with your system being quite busy just changing wallpapers.

Comment: What stops you from using a load indicator applet and do the pscircle magic only every few seconds?

Comment: @EugenRieck is completely right here. In just a second over 100 processes can start and stop in that same second (processes like forking web servers). Changing your wallpaper that frequently will just crash your system.

Comment: Yep, that's what I do, load indicator in Xfce4 menu bar, and PSCircle running every five seconds. Thanks everyone!